# How can I push a part of my git repo to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a multi-module app that is already on Github. It is comprised of two modules, one of them an Android app and the other a Rails based Web app. So my project's directory structure is in the form of:

```
ProjectRoot
|
+-- web
|
+-- android
|
+-- .git
```

As such I cannot simply `cd` into ProjectRoot and push my app to Heroku as the root folder of the Rails app is `ProjectRoot/web`. Is there a way to push the `web` folder to Heroku? If I turn web into a git sub module, it should be easy to accomplish this, but then I only have 5 private repos on Git and I prefer to consume only 1 repo for my whole app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deploy/push only a subdirectory of my git repo to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539382/how-can-i-deploy-push-only-a-subdirectory-of-my-git-repo-to-heroku)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use `git subtree push`. It will generate a new commit tree with your directory as root, and push it.

```
git subtree push --prefix web heroku master
```

Full documentation is [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: This works great. What if you want to push a specific tag or branch in combination with subtree? Like 'git push heroku yourbranch:master'?

Comment: In this case you cannot use the `subtree push` shortcut and have to chain commands youself. For example: `git push heroku \`git subtree split --prefix web yourbranch\`:master`

Comment: FYI, `git subtree` is now part of core git (no need to install anything as long as you're git version is current)

Answer (score 21):

The `git subtree` command (built in, now) is a good way to do this. If you want to push a subtree of a branch to become your master, you can use something like:

`` git push --force heroku `git subtree split --prefix web HEAD`:master ``

Answer (score 4):

You could also use git branches instead of subfolders. If you have git 1.7.2 or newer, you can simply do `git checkout --orphan android` to create a branch that is disconnected from your master branch (assumed here to be the web folder). Once you have checked out the orphan branch, run `git rm -rf .` to remove existing files before copying in your android-specific files to the now empty root directory.

If you want to use separate folders for each module, you can clone the repository twice and use this structure:

```
ProjectRoot
├── android
│   └── .git
└── web
    └── .git
```