# Deploy ember-cli and rails api

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ember-cli

I'm looking for a way to deploy on Heroku a Rails API and an ember-cli application.  My directories structure is something like that:

- application

  - frontend
  - rails-api

Can someone help me? I'm really new Heroku user.

PS: I don't want to use gems like 'ember-cli-rails'

Comment: Heroku is very easy to deploy to if you are using one of their predefined app containers. You are not, so you'll need a custom Heroku build pack combining Rails and Ember. You might want to look around and see if someone has created one, otherwise you have to build one..Here's a place to start https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks --

Comment: I read about that but i don't found anything like what i'm trying to do. Maybe it is because my ignorance.

Comment: You will need a custom build pack in order to deploy a non-default app to Heroku. You could contact Heroku support and ask them if they have any plans to supply a ember/rails app deploy script. For someone without production app deployment experience, the simpler option is to use the ember gem and use the default Rails app slug creation/deployment Heroku offers. Good luck with whatever you decide.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977234/how-can-i-push-a-part-of-my-git-repo-to-heroku) explains how you can push specific folders to heroku.  In general though you will find it a lot easier keeping your application split across separate repos.

Answer (score 1):

I would deploy them separately, and keep them in separate git repos.

## Ember

Use [ember-cli-deploy](https://ember-cli.github.io/ember-cli-deploy/).  I would suggest you look into the [ember-cli-deploy-lightning-pack](https://github.com/ember-cli-deploy/ember-cli-deploy-lightning-pack). There is a presentation about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZVYP3cPcWQ).

This automates the release process -

- Builds your Ember app, with asset fingerprints
- gzips the assets
- Uploads changed files to AWS S3
- Puts the full content of your `index.html` into Redis

## Rails

- deploy your rails-api app to heroku normally
- include a redis addon
- set up the route which serves index.html to query it directly from Redis instead
- I would suggest aliasing all non-api routes (ie a catchall route) to the root route so you can 'deep link' to your ember app

A big advantage of this process is that you can deploy changes to your frontend very quickly, and without having to take down or restart the server.