# "git <refspec> does not look like a ref" trying to link a local branch to a remote Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I've set up a Heroku app, `lucy-staging`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git remote -v
staging https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git (fetch)
staging https://git.heroku.com/lucy-staging.git (push)
```

I have a local branch, `custom-error-views`, which I'd like to push to the `master` branch of the `staging` remote. I'm trying to follow https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps by using the command `git push staging custom-error-views:master`, adapted to push a Git subtree:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git subtree push staging custom-error-views:master --prefix lucy-web/
'custom-error-views:master' does not look like a ref
```

I don't understand this `does not look like a ref` error; it seems analogous to the `development:master` ref in the Heroku documentation. Can anyone point out what is wrong here?

**Update**

It would appear from the source code (https://github.com/github/git-msysgit/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh) that this error message is thrown specifically for `git subtree`s. It reduces to the fact that [`git check-ref-format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) returns a non-zero error code:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git check-ref-format custom-error-views:master
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I have not used `git subtree` for anything real, but it looks like `git subtree push` starts by running `git subtree split`, producing a new commit chain and producing its hash ID. `git subtree push` then pushes that hash ID to a remote reference: `git push <hash>:<ref>`. It therefore makes no sense for you to supply a local reference via a refspec: you'll get a remote-tracking name corresponding to the remote's branch name if you are pushing to a branch name on the remote and you have the appropriate `fetch` setting for the remote.

Comment: I got this error and decided to update git. With git 2.33.1 - which is not yet in the default apt-get repository it seems I no longer get that error. (I currently get a remote permission error instead which feels more expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to push the subtree to the master branch of the remote using the following command:

```
git push staging `git subtree split --prefix lucy-web staging`:master
```

This can be summarized as the following:

```
git push [REMOTE_NAME] `git subtree split --prefix [SUBDIR_PATH] [BRANCH]`:master
```

Using this summary, the example above has the following structure:

- **Remote Name** - staging
- **Subdir Path** - lucy-web
- **Branch** - staging

This is similar to one of the answers given at [How can I push a part of my git repo to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977234/how-can-i-push-a-part-of-my-git-repo-to-heroku)

Comment: Hi, this does not seem to solve the question, how can you pick the branch to push with this syntax? E.g I want to push the branch "develop" instead of master?